# Rigify problem with floating bones

Tags: rigging, rigify

just wanted to ask, I'm learning Rigify and why are those green circles just standing in the air like that? I see that in this tutorial they are also standing like this. Is this normal? Should something be done to fix them? Example: [image] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rigify Rigs every limb has two animation systems: IK and FK. When you select a bone of a limb, in the N properties panel you will see an IK/FK slider that lets you choose which control bones chain to use.

In your example you're using IK, if you switch the slider to FK the limbs will go to the floating bones.

We generally turn off the visibility of the unused bone chains using bone layers (3.6 and older versions) or bone collections (4.0 and above).